# Is it possible to build a .NET Core library for a UWP project targeting Windows 10 Creators Update (15063)?

Tags: .net-core, uwp

I'm writing a UWP app, but one of the bits I've developed is something I want to release separately, as a library. I'd like to use .NET Core for maximum portability, but VS won't let me add a .NET Core library to my UWP project as a reference.

Are there any versions of .NET Core that are supported on Windows 10 Creators Update, aka version 15063? If not, how can I make my library portable - am I just stuck building two libraries for UWP and .NET Core?

Comment: It is impossible. https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff You can usually use a .NET Standard class library project.

Comment: Lex is totally right that .NET Standard is the way to go. If you need to support "old" Windows 10 (16298-) you'll need NS 1.6. otherwise 2.0 will be fine. Adding support for legit .NET Core in UWP apps is something being worked on for .NET Core 5 but I haven't seen any concrete plans yet...